# Register com4j*.dll on 64bit win 2008 r2 Server and run OTAClient

Tags: java, 64-bit, hp-quality-center, com4j

I have tried all the solutions available on net for registering the right dll.

**First the Issue:**
One third party tool uses OTAClient jar which was created through com4j bridge.
While creating the tool, the script works fine in local(64 bit) and connection to QC is *successful*. Mind it, we have to keep com4j.jar in Server lib to avoid repetitive object creation-did that!

But when we try to put the same code with updated jar(OTAClient) which is registered on the production server(Which is Win2008 r2 64Bit), we get the following error:

```
com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 80040154 CoCreateInstance failed : Class not registered : .\com4j.cpp:153
```

**Now the Solutions tried and failed**

Seen many posts on net regarding registering the dll's etc but found that:

1. OTAClient is already in the registry and the jar is using the same Pid's for reference. So no issue with OTAClient.dll registry
2. com4j is placed in server lib as required. So no issues with jar
3. com4j extracted com4j-x86.dll in local but i can find only com4j-amd64.dll created in server machine - CAN BE THE ISSUE - but couldnt figure out how to solve this!

Need pointers on this.

Comment: Update: A simple project for connection when run through eclipse, actually works with same jar and same com4j. But on Server its not able to connect to QC. Need directions on this.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. Mine works on a server, but not my local workspace... same issue with 64 vs 32-bit system I guess. Don't have any solution yet.

Comment: Well, KjetilNordin, after beating my head with OTAClient, I reached to a situation where going for REST services provided by ALM is far much better than OTA. I found these issues:
1. OTAClient can handle one login at a time on the machine, so if you want to cross check the changes on QC/ALM UI, BAM!! your other application would give exceptions.
2. Its much more difficult to get the methods or interfaces since no proper documentation could be found on JAVA sources.
3. REST is fast and flexible. OTA is not.
So, if you can, move to REST asap

Comment: I have also discovered the REST-api recently. I do not think I will implement it on the previous system I was working on, but we are looking into some additional atumated testing tools that needs to integrate with QC, and I will for sure use the REST-api on that system.